# PHP Upload File Types

Tags: php, file

I currently am building a file uploader for a site im building and i have a problem with file types, I need it to be able to upload html, css, javascript, json files, but not PHP etc. My problem is i cant seem to figure out the file type names. See below for more detail.

```
<?php
 if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
 else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
 echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
   }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Where it has image/jpeg, i have tried .html and html to no avail, as well as .js etc and i just cannot figure it out! HELP!!! :D

Comment: try adding more comparison against $_FILES['file']['type'] at IF, for example text/html

Comment: Note that filetype / mimetype can be spoofed, it's not reliable

Comment: @jayhassett89: Why do you want to prevent PHP files? Is it because of security? Because if it is so, uploading HTML (or in that case even JPGs/etc for some browsers) can get you an XSS attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to:

```
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
```

This is the mime type.  If you want to look at the file extension, you have to parse the filename itself. E.G:

```
$ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES["file"]["name"], '.'), 1);
```

To allow/disallow, it's a good idea to use switch:

```
switch ($_FILES["file"]["type"]) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/gif':
        // Allowed
    break;
    default:
        // Not allowed
    break;
}


switch ($ext) {
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'gif':
    case 'jpg':
        // Allowed
    break;
    default:
        // Not allowed
    break;
}
```

Comment: `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` can be spoofed!

Comment: thank you, the file extension was probably a better idea anyways security wise, sorry if my question was unclear :)

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a different approach?

Instead of relying on file type, examine the extension.

Little example of this would be:

```
$parts = array();
$parts = explode( ".", $_FILES['file']['name'] );

if ( !empty($parts) && is_array($parts) ) {
    $extension = end( $parts );
} else {
    echo "File name has no extension";
}

if ( $extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" ) {
    // Do something with the jpeg
} elseif ( $extension == "html" ) {
    // Do something with html
} elseif ( $extension == "js" ) {
    // Do something with js
} else if ( ... /* You can add any conditional based on extension here */ ) {
    // And do whatever you want here
}
```

This is a vary basic, crude example with multiple if / elseif statements, you can make a switch condition, make a factory class, etc... But the idea stays the same.

Cheers.

Comment: Having if trees like this is generally not good practise. You should use switch/case instead.

Comment: Agreed, I noted this is just a "top of the head example" and that it should be done differently under the code sample. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to rely on the client file type in `$_FILES`, you'd better get it from the file content.

```
function mime_type($file_path)
{
    if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {            
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, null);
        $mime_type = $finfo->file($file_path);
    }
    if (!$mime_type && function_exists('passthru') && function_exists('escapeshellarg')) {
        ob_start();
        passthru(sprintf('file -b --mime %s 2>/dev/null', escapeshellarg($file_path)), $return);
        if ($return > 0) {
            ob_end_clean();
            $mime_type = null;
        }
        $type = trim(ob_get_clean());
        if (!preg_match('#^([a-z0-9\-]+/[a-z0-9\-\.]+)#i', $type, $match)) {
            $mime_type = null;
        }
        $mime_type = $match[1];
    }
    return $mime_type;
}
```